# Получение корня из BigInteger (больших чисел)

Tags: java

Что-то `sqrt` у него не заметил.

Comment: Вообще пишу сканер для поиска корней в числах длинной от 9 - 100 цифр.
Берётся число от 9 знаков и циклом проверяется на корни от 2 - 100
скорость критична.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот попытка найти решение в лоб (методом деления отрезка пополам)

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class BigRoot {
    public static BigInteger roots(BigInteger number, int power) throws Exception
    {
        Double d = number.doubleValue();
        BigInteger x1;
        if(Double.isInfinite(d)) {
            String strapprox = number.toString();
            x1 = new BigInteger(strapprox.substring(0, strapprox.length()/7));
        } else {
            String strapprox = String.valueOf(Math.exp(Math.log(number.doubleValue())/power));
            x1 = new BigInteger(strapprox.substring(0, strapprox.indexOf('.')));
        }
        BigInteger x2 = number.divide(x1.pow(power-1));
        switch (x1.compareTo(x2)) {
        case 0: return x1;
        case 1: {BigInteger w = x1;
            x2 = x1;
            x1 = w;
            break;
            }
        default: break;
        }
        while(x2.subtract(x1).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0) {
            BigInteger w = x1.add(x2).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
            switch(w.pow(power).compareTo(number)) {
            case -1: x1 = w;
                break;
            case 0:  return w;
            case 1:  x2 = w;
                break;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalAccessException(number.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант решения, покороче и несколько скоростнее. Выдает число b, для которого b*b = N. Используется итерационный алгоритм Ньютона: b=(b+N/b)/2.

```
    final BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");

public BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger N)
{
    BigInteger result=N.divide(TWO);
    while(result.multiply(result).subtract(N).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE.divide(new BigInteger("100000000")))>0)
        result=result.add(N.divide(result)).divide(TWO);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: compareTo(BigInteger.ONE.divide(new BigInteger("100000000"))

- это настройка точности приближения. Если ее уменьшить, можно ускорить процесс вычисления, уменьшив количество итераций. Поэкспериментируйте. Главное - лишних объектов внутри корневычисляющего метода не создавайте, иначе засорите память.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете написать код для вычисления квадратного корня самостоятельно. Например, используя  простейший [алгоритм](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29). Если нужна большая скорость, есть и более оптимальные [алгоритмы](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/count_fast/intsqrt.php).

Образец:

```
public static BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger number, BigInteger trial)
{
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger a = result;
    BigInteger b = result;

    boolean first = true;

    while (result.compareTo(trial) != 0) {

        if (!first)
            trial = result;
        else
            first = false;

        result = number.divide(trial).add(trial).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));

        if (result.equals(b)) {
            return a;
        }

        b = a;
        a = result;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: `result = number.divide(trial).add(trial).divide(BigIntegerTWO);`

Непонятно :( откуда поле `BigIntegerTWO`?) Что за метод `divide`?

И надо в такой последовательности читать: берем поле number, применяем метод divide, потом применяем метод add, потом применяем метод divide?

Comment: Поправил, вместо BigIntegerTWO - BigInteger.valueOf(2). Читать слева направо.

Comment: что делает trial ? какое значение не подаю, результат не меняет.
как сделать чтобы вычислялся разный корень вместо trial?

Comment: trial -- пробное значение. Чем ближе к значению корня, тем меньше итераций. Если уж очень хочется, то можно взять что нибудь типа

        String strapprox = String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(number.doubleValue()));
        BigInteger trial = new BigInteger(strapprox.substring(0, strapprox.indexOf('.')));

Но BigInteger.ONE -- тоже вполне себе приближение.

Comment: а что насчёт вычисления произвольных целочисленных корней?

Comment: @hitma249 Непонятен вопрос. Что значит "произвольные целочисленные корни" и чем не подходить функция от @Привет?

Comment: to alexlz тем, что кроме расчета квадратного корня он больше ничего не умеет.  
поэтому особой ценности в коде нет, так как требуется подставлять разные корни для вычислений(кроме квадратных и кубических)

Comment: @hitman249 так что надо-то? Какие корни, какие числа (только положительные или нет), какой результат должен быть в случае, если целого корня n степени у числа нет? А то претензия к sqrt насчёт корней разных степеней весьма странная

Comment: to alexlz,   
>> если целого корня n степени у числа нет?   
то ничего не выводить, или если нельзя так, выводить чтото вроде эксепшен  
>> только положительные или нет  
и то и то(по сути не важно), главное чтобы это был целочисленный корень из целочисленного числа.