# Получение произвольного корня из BigDecimal

Tags: java, математика

Есть [подобная](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/82135/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-biginteger-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) тема, как делать то же самое на `BigDecimal`. Извиняюсь, но в этих функциях (вычислениях) я дуб :(

Comment: Уже был [вопрос про извлечение корня произвольной степени](http://hashcode.ru/questions/63460/).

Comment: как вычислить с помощью примеров той темы любой корень в числе включающим 3600 знаков ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте библиотеку [ApFloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/api-index.html). Она содержит функции для вычисления **любого** корня из чисел с плавающей точкой произвольной точности.

```
public static Apfloat root(Apfloat x,  long n)
    throws ArithmeticException, ApfloatRuntimeException
```

Comment: >> квадратного корня   
в том то и дело, что нужно вычислять произвольный корень

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Код:

    Apfloat test = new Apfloat("590490000000000");
    System.out.println(ApcomplexMath.root(test, 10).doubleValue());  

Вывод  

> 29.999999999999996  

Как повысить точность?